# Проверить див на пустоту и выполнить действие

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Есть отправка комментариев,нужно проверить пустой ли див ,и если он пустой то не отправлять комментарий.Цель сделать ,чтобы пустые комментарии не отправлялись.Изначально нужно проверить div на пустоту,если он пустой ничего не делать.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".commen-text").submit(function() {
        if($(".KEmoji_Input div").val()=="") {
                $(this).remove();
        }
    });
 });



<div class="story-wrap">

    <div class="commen-text">
        <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; height: 80px !important;" id="{{STORY_ID}}but" onkeyup="postComment($('#{{STORY_ID}}but .KEmoji_Input div').html(),{{STORY_ID}},{{PUBLISHER_ID}},event);"></div>
        <p class="hideshow">Введите сообщение...</p>
    </div>

   <button onclick="postCommentButton($('#{{STORY_ID}}but .KEmoji_Input div').html(),{{STORY_ID}},{{PUBLISHER_ID}},event)" class="send-comm">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".KEmoji_Input div").text()`

Comment: стоит добавить разметку, к которой ты хочешь применить данный код

Comment: @Grundy конечно, этих `".KEmoji_Input div"` там много

Comment: а теперь разметку с `.KEmoji_Input div`

Comment: А разве .submit() применяется к каким-то элементам помимо форм?

Comment: судя по всему, нужно идти в `postCommentButton` и там проверять что передали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал чуть по другому

```
$('html').keydown(function(e){
    var kemojidiv = $('.KEmoji_Input div');
    if (event.keyCode == 13 ) {
    if (kemojidiv.html() == 0 ) return false;
    $('.send-comm').click()
    kemojidiv.html()
    }
});
```

Comment: логичнее будет проверять на равенство пустой строке, а не числу 0

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали,только теперь если поставить пробелы все равно отправляются пустые сообщения.

Comment: есть метод `.trim()`

Comment: его надо приравнять к 0?

Comment: нет, его надо сравнить с пустой строкой

Comment: $('html').keydown(function(e){
    var kemojidiv = $('.KEmoji_Input div');
    if (event.keyCode == 13 ) {
    if (kemojidiv.html() == '' || kemojidiv.html() == '<br><br>' || kemojidiv.trim() == '')  return false;
    $('.send-comm').click()
    kemojidiv.html()
    }
});

Comment: Все равно вывод пустые комментарии,когда ставлю пробел

Comment: `kemojidiv.html().trim() == ''`

Comment: не ,все равно выводит если пробел поставить

Answer (score 2):

Есть псевдо-селектор `:empty`

```js
$('.isEmpty:empty').remove();
```

```css
.isEmpty {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:#fe4;
margin:5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="isEmpty"></div>
<div class="isEmpty">not</div>
<div class="isEmpty">not</div>
```